# Spring AOP implementation is not working for my project using @Aspect

Tags: spring-boot, aop

Aspect class:

```
    package com.phynart.cloud.aop;

    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class MyAspect {

        @Pointcut("execution(com.phynart.cloud.*.*(..))")
        public void before() {      
            // Advice
            System.out.print("Advice");
        }   
    }
```

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.phynart</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloud</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>websocket-phynart</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
                      <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.113</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.114</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sns -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.115</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
                <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.12</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.3</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors
                </artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
                <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hashids</groupId>
                <artifactId>hashids</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3</version>
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>       
            <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies> 
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <outxml>true</outxml>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                        <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                        </aspectLibraries>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Main class used:
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebsocketPhynartApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebsocketPhynartApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

When I hit any of the method endpoint the aspect class does not print "Advice" which should actually, I am very new to Aspect Oriented Programming, could anyone kindly help me out? Let me know what else I need to add in my project, m i missing something? Moreover if I use @Before instead of PointCut then it gives me error like "pointcut is not well-formed"

Comment: Could you show us the way you load components your pointcut should intercept into your application?

Comment: I did not actually understand your question, I will add more details for clarification, i did not use @ComponentScan

Comment: There are numerous ways to load Spring beans into an application. This can be done through the bean factory / application context or dependency injection. I would like to see how you load a reference of the Spring bean in the com.phynart.cloud package that you think should print "Advice" when you call any method on it.

Comment: I have added a main class "WebsocketPhynartApplication' which runs spring application, i think it load automatically every component

Comment: You'll have to mark configuration class `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to enable aspects

Comment: i added EnableAspectJAutoProxy, still not working @wildDev, tried just now

Comment: package com.phynart.cloud.restcontroller;
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
 public ResponseEntity<Object> test() throws Exception {

  return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Hello World", HttpStatus.OK);
 }


whenever i hit on "/test" -"advice" does not print - only prints "Hello World"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Before` or `@After` should do the job. Change your aspect component to something like that

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.phynart.cloud.*.*(..))")
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("Advice");
    }

}
```

I don't think you need to annotate your `@Configuration` class with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` since you're using Spring Boot, but in a Spring framework-based application, that would be necessary.